Ubuntu 24.04 - Nvidia Brightness reset issue on second screen
I have installed the Ubuntu 24.04 yesterday and as I found a few issues, I have upgraded Nvidia driver to 550;
I have an external monitor and seems it doesn't hold the configuration for this screen. Even if I set the Brightness, Contrast and Gamma and save it. After I reboot the laptop I need to open the NVIDIA X Server Settings to make it load the configuration; And even doing it this way, sometimes it resets the values to 0 when I'm using the laptop.
In some cases, I only need to open the Nvidia Settings again, and it reloads the config, but sometimes it doesn't load, and I need to set it all again;

Does someone knows how to solve this bug?
On my logs I have filtered it by Nvidia and seems it had some activities

